# GridView and Eval

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to pass a value through Eval in my GridView, but instead of passing the actual value, it passes the string '<%# Eval etc...This is my code, can anybody advise?

```
enter code here<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" OnClientClick="loadDialog('<%# Eval(PK_SpecialEvent).ToString() %>') " Text="Upload/Open Files" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("PK_SpecialEvent", "loadDialog(\"{0}\");") %>'
```

Another, more readable, way is to do this in codebehind. A good place would be in GridView's [RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).

Comment: Thanks...I was testing in Firefox which I still cannot get this to work in, but it works in IE

Answer (score -2):

I've only done a GridView once before in my so-far beginners experience of ASP.NET, but should the:-

`Eval(PK_SpecialEvent).ToString()`

have quotes added in to become like:

`Eval("PK_SpecialEvent").ToString()`

At least - it does in my working code of a GridView.